# JSONB array to comma-separated string without using group by in postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
my_column_name  jsonb not null default '[]'::jsonb
```

I have a jsonb column which is guaranteed to be an array of strings. How can I select it as a comma-separated string.
For example, If the column value is `["foo", "bar"]` the selection should return `foo,bar` (text) (Note: no quotes and no spaces).

For `[]`, it should just give an empty string.

What have I tried so far:

```
select translate(my_column_name::TEXT, '[]" ', '')
```

But it may not work if I have those characters within the array itself.

I also want to avoid CTEs, custom functions, group by as much as possible.

Comment: Combine built-in string_agg with json_array_elements_text functions.

Comment: "*I also want to avoid CTEs, custom functions, group by as much as possible.*" - why would you? Those are exactly the things that you should use.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a function for that:

```
create function json_array_to_csv(p_input jsonb)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(x.item, ',' order by idx)
  from jsonb_array_elements_text(p_input) with ordinality as x(item, idx);
$$ 
language sql
immutable;
```

Then

```
select json_array_to_csv('["foo", "bar"]');

json_array_to_csv
-----------------
foo,bar
```

If for some strange (and incomprehensible) reason you don't want to use a custom function and make your life harder than it needs to be, you can use it as a scalar-subquery in the column list of a SELECT query:

```
select some_column, 
       other_column,
       (select string_agg(x.item, ',' order by idx)
        from jsonb_array_elements_text(the_jsonb_column) with ordinality as x(item, idx)
       ) as items
from the_table;
```

But I would always prefer:

```
select some_column, 
       other_column,
       json_array_to_csv(the_jsonb_column) as items
from the_table;
```